# Prediction from the Vilna Gaon that America would be the last exile . I am looking for the source?

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, golus-exile, vilna-gaon

I have heard from numerous people this prediction of the Vilna Gaon that America would be the last exile/galus but I have no idea where this actually comes from. I just wanted to know if anyone could validate this for me or provide the source of this.

Thanks

Comment: I heard it was R Chaim Volozhin :) and that he cried profusely.

Comment: Here quoted from R. Chaim Soloveitchik (by R. Pinchas Hirschprung) https://books.google.com/books?id=f-KiDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT261&lpg=PT261&dq=Vilna+Gaon+that+America+would+be+the+last+exile/&source=bl&ots=WIW3nXr-oz&sig=i8gTSTi0BHWdG-U5xm1G3xe-kko&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq95iXtMzTAhXBNiYKHS8mAloQ6AEIDDAB#v=onepage&q=Vilna%20Gaon%20that%20America%20would%20be%20the%20last%20exile%2F&f=false

Comment: And here quoted from R. Chaim Halberstam (the Divrei Chaim) https://books.google.com/books?id=f-KiDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT261&lpg=PT261&dq=Vilna+Gaon+that+America+would+be+the+last+exile/&source=bl&ots=WIW3nXr-oz&sig=i8gTSTi0BHWdG-U5xm1G3xe-kko&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq95iXtMzTAhXBNiYKHS8mAloQ6AEIDDAB#v=onepage&q=Vilna%20Gaon%20that%20America%20would%20be%20the%20last%20exile%2F&f=false

Comment: And here (n. 86) cited in the name of R. Chaim of Volozhin http://traditionarchive.org/news/converted/Volume%2030/No.%204/A%20Glimpse%20of%20the%20Rav.pdf

Comment: Another place that attributes it to R. Chaim of Volozhin is [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41925&pgnum=194), citing the book "אבי הישיבות: תולדות חייו ומשנתו של ר' חיים מוולוז'ין" as it's source.

Answer (score 3):

Zev Eleff wrote an article about this story, [here](https://www.academia.edu/44937758/_Rabbi_Hayim_of_Volozhin_Rabbi_Aharon_Kotler_and_the_Remaking_of_an_American_Jewish_Prophecy_). In it he writes:

> It is not possible to verify the historicity of the legend. Rabbi Hayim did not record it, nor is the account mentioned by his disciples in the ﬁrst decades of the nineteenth century. Jews in Eastern Europe were vaguely aware of the American Revolution but had little contact with the ﬂedging American Jewish communities and the one thousand women and men who inhabited them.
> European Jewry’s awareness of their American counterparts signiﬁcantly increased in the second half of the nineteenth century, long after Rabbi Hayim may or may not have predicted America as an eventual destination for Jewish life and Torah study.

However, he goes on to describe the source as provided by R. Aharon Soloveichik: According to R. Aharon, R. Chaim Volozhiner said this in the presence of his son, R. Itzele, who transmitted it to his son-in-law, the Netziv, who then repeated it at the bar mitzvah of his great grandson, R. Moshe Soloveitchik, father of R. Aharon.

Answer (score 2):

Approximately, 200 years ago, Rav Chaim Volozhin told Reb Dovid the following:

> *“…You should know, my son, that the day will come when the pillars of European Jewry will topple, when the yeshivos will be destroyed and
>   uprooted. However, they will be reborn in the exile of America, the
>   final stop of the Jewish people before the arrival of Moshiach. The
>   American exile will be the tenth and final exile of Torah, following
>   those of Babylon, North Africa, Egypt, Italy, Spain, France, Germany,
>   Poland and Lithuania”*

[see [*Daring to Dream*](http://bit.ly/1ryCZXx) by Agudath Israel of America, page 128 and *[Exile](https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/76339)*].

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Chaim of Volozhin (1749-1821), the prime disciple of the Vilna Gaon who famously authored the Kabbalistic work Nefesh HaChaim said this:

> "The last stanza [way station] to which Torah will be exiled before the advent of Mashiach is America."

Quotation taken from [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1422615022) book.

Comment: So what's *their* source?